# Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 64 values, but the requested shape has 4

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am working on face detection task and I am new to computer vision. but i am getting some issue I have tried with some change but not work for me.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load("images.npy",allow_pickle=True)


IMAGE_HEIGHT=224
IMAGE_WIDTH=224
masks = np.zeros((int(data.shape[0]), IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH))
X_train = np.zeros((int(data.shape[0]), IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3))
for index in range(data.shape[0]):
   img = data[index][0]
   img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
   try:
     img = img[:, :, :3]
   except:
     continue
   X_train[index] = preprocess_input(np.array(img, dtype=np.float32))
   for i in data[index][1]:
      x1 = int(i["points"][0]['x'] * IMAGE_WIDTH)
      x2 = int(i["points"][1]['x'] * IMAGE_WIDTH)
      y1 = int(i["points"][0]['y'] * IMAGE_HEIGHT)
      y2 = int(i["points"][1]['y'] * IMAGE_HEIGHT)
      masks[index][y1:y2, x1:x2] = 1


      model.fit(X_train,masks, epochs=30,batch_size = 1, verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint, reduce_lr, stop])
```

I have read image data from image.npy

after executing above code and getting below error:

```
  validArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
     (0) Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 64 values, but the requested shape has 4
     [[{{node reshape/Reshape}}]]
     [[loss/mul/_1213]]
     (1) Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 64 values, but the requested shape has 4
     [[{{node reshape/Reshape}}]]
     0 successful operations.
     0 derived errors ignored.
```

data format is as below

```
    array([array([[[207, 216, 227, 255],
    [206, 216, 227, 255],
    [207, 216, 227, 255],
    ...,
    [ 35,  33,  34, 255],
    [ 35,  33,  34, 255],
    [ 35,  33,  34, 255]],

   [[207, 216, 227, 255],
    [207, 216, 227, 255],
    [207, 216, 227, 255],
    ...,
    [ 35,  32,  33, 255],
    [ 35,  33,  34, 255],
    [ 35,  33,  34, 255]],

   [[207, 216, 227, 255],
    [207, 216, 227, 255],
    [207, 215, 227, 255],
    ...,
    [ 35,  33,  33, 255],
    [ 35,  33,  34, 255],
    [ 35,  33,  34, 255]],

   ...,

   [[ 31,  21,  17, 255],
    [ 31,  22,  18, 255],
    [ 31,  22,  18, 255],
    ...,
    [  0,   1,   4, 255],
    [  0,   1,   4, 255],
    [  0,   1,   4, 255]],

   [[ 31,  22,  18, 255],
    [ 31,  22,  18, 255],
    [ 31,  22,  18, 255],
    ...,
    [  0,   1,   4, 255],
    [  0,   1,   4, 255],
    [  0,   1,   4, 255]],

   [[ 31,  22,  18, 255],
    [ 30,  22,  17, 255],
    [ 31,  22,  18, 255],
    ...,
    [  0,   1,   4, 255],
    [  0,   1,   4, 255],
    [  0,   1,   4, 255]]], dtype=uint8),

     list([{'label': ['Face'], 'notes': '', 'points': [{'x': 
     0.7053087757313109, 'y': 0.23260437375745527}, {'x': 
     0.7692307692307693, 'y': 0.36182902584493043}], 'imageWidth': 1280, 
     'imageHeight': 697}])],
     dtype=object)
```

I am just confused with what will be x and y and how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You might be using `tf.reshape` in some function in your code.

The `tf.reshape` does not change the order of or **the total number of elements in the tensor**. The error as states, you are trying to reduce total number of elements from 64 to 4.

In below example, I have recreated your scenario where I have the given the `shape` argument as `2` for `tf.reshape` which doesn't accommodate all the elements of original tensor, thus throws the error -

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
t1 = tf.Variable([1,2,2,4,5,6])

t2 = tf.reshape(t1, 2)
```

**Output -**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0ff1d701ff22> in <module>()
      3 t1 = tf.Variable([1,2,2,4,5,6])
      4 
----> 5 t2 = tf.reshape(t1, 2)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 6 values, but the requested shape has 2 [Op:Reshape]
```

`tf.reshape` should be in such a way that the arrangement of elements can change but total number of elements must remain the same. So the fix would be to change the shape to `[2,3]` -

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
t1 = tf.Variable([1,2,2,4,5,6])

t2 = tf.reshape(t1, [2,3])
print(t2)
```

**Output -**

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2 2]
 [4 5 6]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Rajanikant Shukla - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.